# Two web servers, one gives HTTP Error 503

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net, website, hosted

I have a website done in VisualStudio 2010,.Net 4,c# connecting to Mysql.This site is working fine when hosted in Machine 1(Details Below) but getting hanged(not responding) when hosted in Machine2 after a time period of roughly 7 hours..its showing HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable..

Machine:1 System Config: windows 7 professional service pack 1, processor:intel(R) Core(TM)i5-2400CPU@3.10GHz 3.10GHz, Ram:8 GB, System Type:64-bit OS

IIS Information:: version 6.1(Build 7601:service Pack 1) (version 7.5.7600.16385)

App Pool: ASP.NET v4.0

Machine:2 System Config: windows2008 R2 Enterprise edition processor:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU31220@3.1GHz 3.10GHz, Ram:8 GB, System Type:64-bit OS

IIS Information:: version 6.1(Build 7601:service pack 1)) (version 7.5.7600.16385)

Application pool:ASP.NET v4.0

I need this site to be hosted in machine 2.There are only less than 10 users using the site concurrently.Please Help.

Thank You..

Comment: In the error any more description available? Also have u checked by restarting the IIS?

Comment: A process serving application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '2544'.This is warning found in the IIS Log.

Comment: Check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2634635